# Late Binding Magic under VB.NET converted to C#

Tags: c#, vb.net, c#-4.0

I should convert some code from VB to C#. Given following lines of VB work (I think only because option is not set to strict):

```
Dim someProp As SomeType
Try
    someProp = CType(SomeInstance, Object).SomeProp 
    ' ...
```

Due to late binding, this code is possible under VB. Of course, following won't work under C#:

```
SomeType someProp;
try
{
    someProp = ((object)SomeInstance).SomeProp;
    // ...
```

How could I formulate something similar under C#?

Thx for any tipps
sl3dg3

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're using C# 4.0:

```
SomeType someProp;
try
{
    someProp = ((dynamic)SomeInstance).SomeProp;
    // ...
```

Comment: Yes I do use C# 4.0 - had to add the reference Microsoft.CSharp, seems to work!

Comment: Great! ;) Hopefully I could help you!