# How does VB.NET resolve this to an object property?

Tags: vb.net, properties, late-binding

Ok, so I'm a C# coder, and I have trouble even reading VB.NET, so please forgive what may turn out to be an incredibly dumb question. But I have some code which looks like this:

```
Function GetName(sourceObject as Object) as String
    return sourceObject.Name
End Function
```

So, ignoring the fact that the syntax is probably wrong - how does VB.NET get the Name property from sourceObject? Inspecting it at run-time reveals that sourceObject is of a type that supports a property called Name with a getter, but what does VB.NET do in this case? Is there some extra code that is being generated by the compiler to somehow cast this automagically at run-time?

As you may be able to tell, I'm a little confused. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a case of late binding. So, if the sourceObject contains a property as Name it will return the value otherwise it will just throw an error that property not found.

Late binding in C# requires reflection so it throws compile time error, whereas in vb.net it can be done without reflection.

> The Visual Basic compiler performs a process called binding when an
>   object is assigned to an object variable. An object is early bound
>   when it is assigned to a variable declared to be of a specific object
>   type. Early bound objects allow the compiler to allocate memory and
>   perform other optimizations before an application executes. By
>   contrast, an object is late bound when it is assigned to a variable
>   declared to be of type Object. Objects of this type can hold
>   references to any object.

Comment: Ok thanks - but is there a reference somewhere that can describe to me exactly how it works? Because I need to convert this code to C# and I would like to replicate the functionality in a sane way (i.e. not using reflection if at all possible)...

Comment: Have alook at this msdn link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0tcf61s1.aspx

Comment: This will help you to do late binding in C# http://kristofmattei.be/2010/02/11/c-late-binding/

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8225328/late-binding-magic-under-vb-net-converted-to-c-sharp and http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?t=421966

Comment: Thanks. Informative - although I am pretty sure this makes baby Jesus cry a little bit every time it's used! :)

Comment: +1. And if you don't like this "feature", and I must admit I hate it, use Option Strict On to disable it. Sadly Microsoft say [we can't have the dynamic keyword in VB](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3305275/net-4-0-framework-dynamic-features-in-vb-with-option-strict-on/3608896)

Answer (score 3):

If you are using c# 4.0 then you can try this.

```
return ((dynamic)SourceObject).Name;
```

Answer (score 2):

Because of inherent late binding, all VB variables of type Object are equivalent to c# objects which have been cast to dynamic -- or to put it another way, c# added dynamic in order to gain functional parity with VB.

So, the equivalent c# code would be `((dynamic) sourceObject).Name`

I would look into doing this with Generics or an interface if possible, as thats a cleaner design.

Comment: Yeah I plan on re-doing it with strong typing, but before I refactor something I like to know how it *actually* operates...

Answer (score 1):

Just be aware that VB's Late Binding bypasses type checking with your compiler. If the Object being passed in doesn't have a Name property, an exception could be raised at run time.

Comment: Yep, fully aware of that. That's why I want to understand how it works, so I can get rid of the behaviour.